# XSL loop through faultblock and apppend values to a string without using template

Tags: string, loops, xslt, append

How to loop through fault_block and append values to a string/variable without using template in XSLT. fault_block may occur once or twice or n number of times based on validation errors

Desired Output: 11-Invalid ID;22-Invalid Password;.....nn-Error;

```
<status>
    <code>00</code>
    <description>Success</description>
    <faultblock>
        <faultcode>11</faultcode>
        <faultdesc>Invalid ID</faultdesc>
    </faultblock>
    <faultblock>
        <faultcode>22</faultcode>
        <faultdesc>Invalid Password</faultdesc>
    </faultblock>
    <faultblock>
        <faultcode>nn</faultcode>
        <faultdesc>Error</faultdesc>
    </faultblock>
</status>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without using template". XSLT cannot work without al least one template.

Comment: trying to achieve by using simple <for-each> or any other option. If using template makes it simpler, happy to go with template solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to get your output using only a for-each statement instead of using multiple templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//faultblock">
      <xsl:value-of select="faultcode"/>
      <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="faultdesc"/>
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B71

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, let me try this option